# can i use size class to specify some constraints install/uninstalled for iphone5 only?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I want to make some constraints only be installed for iphone5 in storyboard ,i think the default compact(W)/Regular(H) is be possible for both iphone4 iPhone 5 ,iphone6 ,so how can i distinguish iphone5 in size classing?

Comment: I don't think you can. Only solution is to activate/deactivate such constraints programmatically after identifying the target device.